# error deploying token to ropsten using remix

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, tokens, ropsten

I am trying to deploy my token on Ropsten Network using REMIX IDE, but keep getting this error "**contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly**."

My code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                      ERC20 Interface
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom (address from, address to, uint tokens)   public returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                      Safe Math library
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a); 
        c = a - b; 
    } 
}

contract erc20 is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    
    uint256 public _totalSupply;
    
    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    

    constructor() public {
        name = "erc20";
        symbol = "TCC";
        decimals = 8;
        _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;
        
        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }
    
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply - balances[address(0)];
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }
    
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

[image]
Please tell me where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but it could be related to the fact you cast SafeMath as a contract instead of a library. A contract with only pure functions should always been replaced by a library to save gas during the code execution.

So my advice is to change `contract SafeMath` into `library SafeMath` and `contract erc20 is ERC20Interface, SafeMath` into `contract erc20 is ERC20Interface`.

Also don't forget to add `using SafeMath for uint256;` in your erc20 contract.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're trying to deploy the interface, change this to `erc20`[image]